# Find the coefficients $C_0, C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4$ in a power series

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

The question reads:

> Represent the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{5+x}$ as a power series 
>   $$ f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty=C_nx^n$$
>   and find $C_0, \cdots, C_4$ and the radius of convergence.

So far I know that $C_0$ is $0$, and that the radius of convergence is $5$ because:

Using $\frac{a}{(1-r)}=\sum_{n=0}^n ar^n$ (geometric series) and with $a=5x$, $ r=\frac{-x}{5}$,

by factoring out $\frac{x}{5}*\frac{1}{1-\frac{-x}{5}}$ and $r<1$, so: $\frac{-x}{5}<1$ becomes $x<|5|$.

So the radius of convergence is $5$.

Also, for $\frac{x}{{5}*({1}-\frac{-x}{5})}$, if we multiply it by $5$, it becomes:

$$\frac{a}{(1-r)}=\frac{5x}{1-(\frac{-x}{5})}$$

so $a=5x$ and $r=\frac{-x}{5}$.

However, when I tried to find the coefficients of $C_0$, $C_1\cdots$ I tried representing the function of $\frac{x}{5+x}$ as $c=x^n$, so:

$$C_0=\frac{-x}{5}^0$$

$$C_1=\frac {-x}{5}^1$$

$$C_2=\frac{-x}{5}^2$$ ...

But the answers came up wrong.

I know that $C_n=\frac{(f^n*(a))}{n!}$, but I have no idea how to find the answer.

Are the coefficients:

$$C_0=\frac{\frac{x}{5+x}^0(5x)}{0!}$$

$$C_1=\frac{\frac{x}{5+x}^1(5x)}{1!}$$

$$C_2=\frac{\frac{x}{5+x}^2(5x)}{2!}$$

...

Or am I wrong again?

Could someone please walk me through this step-by-step and provide the answers for the coefficients?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote something (the geometric series) and then tried to use something completely different (Taylor series).

You already wrote that 
$$\tag{1}
f(x)=\frac{x}{5}\,\frac{1}{1-\frac{-x}{5}},
$$
and that
$$\tag{2}
\frac{a}{(1-r)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n
$$
(you had a typo in the upper limit). 
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ you get directly that 
$$
f(x)=\frac x5\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac x5\right)^n
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{n+1}}{5^{n+1}}
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\,\frac{x^n}{5^n}.
$$
Since for the geometric series you need the root to be less than one, you need $|x/5|<1$, that is $|x|<5$. So the radius of convergence is $5$.

Comment: Please remember to also improve the question by editing (at least to make it more readable), so that it is less likely to be closed.